# PHP checkdir() open root folder of the project

Tags: php, scandir

Good day,
I have the following issue with scandir() command in PHP.I need to open the root folder of the project.The concept is quite simple, I'm developing a script which will open the root folder and erase every containing folder/file that do not meet certain parameters. Unfortunately for me this has to be done in PHP. So far I've been working with

```
$dir=scandir('..'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
foreach($dir as $i=>$val){
    if(is_dir($dir[$i])){
    $tmpDir=scandir('..'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$dir[$i]);
    }
}
```

But when i print_r() the $tmpDir i get an an array that represents structure of parent folder of my project(XAMPP/htdocs/). I believe that  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is not the right way of getting root folder's name. It is important that the script is getting root folder's name dynamically as it is to be in other projects. What am i doing wrong and should i do it in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `__FILE__`, then explode on the `/`

As an example:
My script is based at:  `/home/cloud/public/index.php`

That will be the output of `__FILE__`.

Explode will result in:

```
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => home
    [2] => cloud
    [3] => public
    [4] => index.php
)
```

Then you can grab any directory you want and get the name of it.

If you want to know in which folder the script is based, get the one last entry like this:

`$explode[count($explode)-2]`

Will result in:

```
public
```

Full script to get the folder name of the folder where the script is placed:

```
$explode = explode("/", __FILE__);
echo $explode[count($explode)-2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__DIR__` if you are on PHP 5.3, or `dirname(__FILE__)` if < 5.3